# Iterating through a Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

Currently doing a bit of work on parsing a template I made for a small game.

It looks like this:

```
HEADER:NPC
NAME:Goblin
NAMEPLURAL:Goblins
NAMECHILD:Gob'in
NAMECHILDPLURAL:Gob'ins
MOVEMENT0:WALK
MOVEMENT1:RUN
MOVEMENT2:SWIM
BASEHP:30
BASEMANA:0
BASELEVEL:1?9
```

In my parser I do the following:

```
class TemplateParser
{
    public String folder { get; set; }

    public TemplateParser(String folder)
    {
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    public Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> Parse()
    {
        Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> parsedTemplates =
            new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>();

        String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        StreamReader reader;

        foreach (String s in files)
        {
            try
            {
                String line = "";
                reader = new StreamReader(s);
                Dictionary<String, String> attributes = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] split = line.Split(':');
                    attributes.Add(split[0], split[1]);
                }
                parsedTemplates.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s), attributes);
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Log.LogMessage(ioe.Message, ELogFlag.CRITICAL);
            }
        }

        return parsedTemplates;
    }
}
```

Now here is the issue:

When I try to look through this collection (after running `Parse()`) I want to do a little test and write out the dictionary containing all the info from the "Goblin" Dictionary.

So far all my attempts have been futile as when I do `templates["Goblin"]` I would expect I get a dictionary I could iterate over with `foreach()` but it wouldn't let me do that. It said something about the conversion not being possible. Then I look for an Enumerator instead but I couldn't get an enumerator to iterate over either.

What am I missing?

Comment: What exact error do you have?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy It's not so much an error as it frustration over missing the logic for iterating over a dictionary in a dictionary.

Comment: @Vipar The error that you're getting *specifically* mentions what the actual type of the object is though.  If you looked at it it will explain exactly what you need to change the type to.

Comment: @Servy I tried changing it, and it didn't help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code for printing the dictionary, since the compiler "said something about the conversion not being possible," it appears that your code is not using the right element type in your loop.

Here is how you can iterate over a dictionary of dictionaries, regardless of their key types:

```
var dictOfDictionaries = Parse();
foreach (var dictPair in dictOfDictionaries) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", dictPair.Key);
    foreach (var innerPair in dictPair.Value) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:{1}", innerPair.Key, innerPair.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! I completely forgot about the `var` keyword.

Comment: @Vipar You don't *need* `var`.  It just prevents you from needing to type out what the type actually is.  In this case this is certainly worthwhile as the type name is so long and unweildly, but since there are no anonymous types it's not *needed*.  The other answer demonstrates that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
Dictionary<int,Dicationary<string,char>> lol = new Dictionary<int,Dicationary<string,char>>();
foreach( KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string,char>> kvp in lol)
{
    int test = kvp.Key;
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string,char> kvp2 in kvp.Value)
    {
        string s = kvp.Key;
        char c = kvp.Value;
    }
}
```